Maximizing a linear combination of logistic functions
Fix $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the mapping $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$
h(x, y) = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \sigma(a_i x + y)
$$
where $\sigma$ is the logistic function, i.e. $\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$.
$h$ is bounded, continuous and infinitely differentiable.
I am looking for $S = \text{sup}_{(x,y)} h(x, y)$, ideally in closed form as a function of $a$ and $b$. If such closed form does not exist (as I suspect), any qualitative insight would be much appreciated.
What I was able to notice is simply that

$S \ge \pm \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \text{sgn}(a_i)$  (by letting $x$ go to $\pm \infty$ for arbitrary $y$)

$S \ge \pm \sum_{i=1}^n b_i $  (by letting $y$ go to $\pm \infty$ for arbitrary $x$)


Also, obviously, $S \le \sum_{i=1}^n |b_i|$, but I am not able to prove anything stronger.

I’m not an expert, but having a closed formula wouldn’t be too convenient to be true?

i m not an expert either :) indeed as i said i suspect no closed form to exist but you never know. the thing is that even in the absence of a closed form solution you can maybe still have some qualitative insight or partial answers.. or at least so i hope
